# How to publish Android Library on Android Arsenal?

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle, jcenter

i've made a small library for android :

https://github.com/linkindrew/easyFTP

Also uploaded on Bintray, waiting for publish and JCenter approval.How can i make it available to "Free" stuff section on Android Arsenal ?

Here :
https://android-arsenal.com/free

Comment: can you post a link for uploading library on bintray??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no automated submission process like maven/jcenter.  Just use the 
[Contact](http://android-arsenal.com/contact) option and submit details of your library.

I'd also recommend submitting to Android Weekly which features new libraries.  Just submit your repo link at the bottom of the page [here](http://androidweekly.net/)

I've submitted libraries to both via these methods and they do get picked up.

Comment: will i receive notification email from android arsenal ? or its just hit or miss ?

Comment: I didn't get an email response as far as I remember, it's just a case of wait and see.  Certainly Android Weekly vets submissions so you may not get included.  Android Arsenal seems to list most things submitted judging by the volume and similarity of some categories.

Answer (score 9):

You can also consider adding your libs to the new "Awesome Android" list. It's the new kind on the block https://android.libhunt.com/contribute